# Show larger images for high DPI displays

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design, images

Some of the newer tablets and also Notebooks (notably the iPad, Macbook Pro and the Nexus 10 tablet) use displays with ultra-high resolutions at around 300 dpi. This makes text look very, very good, but it also means that images that are not adapted to that resolution can look rather bad in comparison.

Here are some crops from a screenshot from my Nexus 10:

[image]

and

[image]

These show that the StackExchange button and the logo, which contain text and hard edges, looks noticeably softer on a high-resolution display. This is of course no big deal, but it is very noticeable.

It would be nice if at some point some of the common images on SE sites that contain text or other hard edges would be served as high-resolution versions to devices with such high-resolution displays. This is obviously not a critical issue, but it would be nice if it could be tackled at some point.

Comment: SVG for the win! On the other side, that most likely bites with some other browsers...mmhhh...

Comment: The StackExchange button could just be changed to text rather than an image and could the rep up/down buttons become CSS triangles. even the site logos could be mostly text.

Comment: This would really make me happy - I don't like seeing blurry images on my iPad :(

Comment: I'd love to know what noun comes after "How can I give my wife emergency..."

Comment: **bump** I'd really like to see this implemented.

Comment: In particular, I'd love to see higher-res user badges.

Comment: Even just the main site logo would be a start.  Looks really blurry on my MBP Retina.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [How can I give my wife emergency access to logins, passwords, etc.?](http://superuser.com/q/514558/90117) :D

Comment: @Undo you know comments don't bump anything, do you? :)

Comment: @Sha Almost a year ago? Probably not :P

Comment: The Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange logo isn't actually that complicated and could be quite easily made as an SVG.

Comment: Still waiting, seeing that awful pixelated logo every day.  My guess as to why: Stack Exchange is a Windows shop -> Windows is still horrible on high DPI -> there are very few high DPI Windows laptops -> problem doesn't exist.