# HDPI version of Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, screenshot, retina

Is an HDPI version of stack exchange coming to our retina screens? I would be happy to see support for HDPI.

**The first thing to improve is the image uploader**. It should be simple to add a selector for the density of the images we upload to avoid displaying huge screen captures in our questions/answers?

See the related question: [Show larger images for high DPI displays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157821/170241) for an example of how terrible screen captures can look when taken on an HDPI screen and uploaded without prior processing.

Could you also add a way to redefine the density of current images so we can fix the ones that are currently broken without having to replace the HDPI version of our existing images? 
**[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/66702/11600) used to perfectly illustrate the problem - I edited all images with `<img>` tags and hardcoded width/height values)**.

i.e.

[image]

I believe it is better to fix this issue now, while there are few HDPI users rather than later when thousands of posts become disfigured by HDPI screen captures. Currently they really decrease readability and give a very clunky look to the site.

Also let's remember while the Apple retina thing is HDPI, HDPI is not retina. Other screen densities are already out there.

So automatically giving the option to scale to the density of the current display would be the best approach. Reveal other options only when the user requests it.

---

If you are planing HDPI support what will be the best approach when it comes to serving pages to multiple resolution densities? dynamic reloads (javascript reloading of all available images a the right resolution)? css? everything loaded at *2 resolution, introduction of svg graphics?

Concerning gravatar the solution should be prety simple at the moment replace all calls to http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG with http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG for *2 resolution.

Planning ahead will you add support for intermediate resolutions densities (*1.5, *1.75) and for higher ones (*3, *4...)?

Comment: Related: [Show larger images for high DPI displays](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157821/show-larger-images-for-high-dpi-displays)

Comment: Related: [Checkbox to include <img> HTML, or automatically resize a retina display screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161111/checkbox-to-include-img-html-or-automatically-resize-a-retina-display-screens).

Comment: Note that the subject sounds like it is all-encompassing, but the feature-request mostly covers user-supplied images. Although it is a lesser issue, I'd love to see the static, site-supplied images also made high resolution (as in the first "Related" question above).

Comment: [Coming soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225821/stack-exchange-multicollider-superdropdown-image-wacked#comment738510_225859)! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Great news! thank you! Is there an official post about this somewhere?

Comment: Not yet, your question is currently in the head of a chain regarding retina display support so guess when it will be done Nick will post answer right here. :)

Comment: They [acknowledge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310939/282094) that this is a problem, now that there are many more high DPI displays and the CSS isn't supporting them.