# Can the Gravatar images be sized to support HDPi displays?

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-picture, gravatar, user-card

When requesting a Gravatar image that's 32x32 and displaying it inside an `<img>` tag whose width and height are also set to 32x32, you end up with a blurry image being displayed to users with high density displays:

[image]

Is there any way to just change the query string from `s=32` to `s=64`? Or rather, is there a way to set the `s` query string to twice the size of the image that you want to display?

Comment: Is it working fine with non-gravatar avatars?

Comment: @ShadowWizard not sure. I only noticed with my avatar which is a Gravatar-hosted image. Do you have a link to a page with a non-gravatar avatar in it? I'd be happy to test.

Comment: Sure, any of my questions/answers. (using imgur hosting)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, they are also blurry. I'll update the question with another image in a few minutes.

Comment: Well, it's part of [this bigger feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161373/hdpi-version-of-stack-exchange).

Comment: @ShadowWizard perfect! Sounds like you guys are already on it. Thanks!

Comment: Not really, there's still  no official response in there. :(

Comment: Extremely poor example you used here.