# Add high-resolution-graphics and / or .svg-icons

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I think that Stack Exchange could optimize the Stack Overflow logo on top of the page for high-resolution displays.

Moreover I think that svg-Files are a better solution for simple icons like upvote or down vote, which will look sharp on all devices and often have even a smaller size than png-files.

Comment: Related feature request of mine "[Show larger images for high DPI displays"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157821/show-larger-images-for-high-dpi-displays), maybe even a duplicate though I don't think SVG is the right solution.

Comment: Why don't you think that SVG is the right solution, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926285/svg-browser-support) there is no real browser-supporting issue, for older IE-versions you could use VML's

Comment: The "explained here" part is really lacking any citation.

Comment: @TravisJ: There "here" is clickable.

Comment: I haven't looked into this in detail and it was quite a while ago, but my impression was that browser support is not that good for anything but the minimal feature set, and I would also suspect that for small icons like e.g. the SE bubble in the top left, a hand-optimized PNG in the proper resolution would look better than a scaled SVG.

Comment: I thought that icons like the upvote and downvote, the favorite icon as well as the badges could be replaced with SVG. For things like the StackExchange icon or Stack Overflow icon I would prefer a larger image, too.

Comment: Is there a bug anywhere about how "here" doesn't look clickable in Anthimos' comment above, since it is covered by the name box directly below it?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find one, [so...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201811/links-do-not-appear-clickable-in-comments-depending-on-placement)

Comment: They could start by fixing the logo (this is going to kill me) ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181340/logo-is-slightly-misaligned/181350#181350

Comment: Basic SVGs (such as would be appropriate for logos, buttons, arrows, etc.) are solidly supported everywhere but old IE (for which a PNG fallback is perfectly appropriate...no high PPI displays run IE8). Font-based icons (supported IE7+) may be appropriate for some cases as well. Both will give razor-sharp results across every device I've tested (PC, Mac, iPad, iPhone, Android phones/tablets, Chromebooks, Windows phone/Surface).

Answer (score 4):

A lot of our sites have been moved to a new refactored LESS set up. During the conversion process we have been converting site logos and icons to SVG. For example, this has been implemented on Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User already.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve created web-optimized SVG versions of the logos provided on https://stackexchange.com/about/logos.

- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/stack-exchange-logos)
- [Demo](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/stack-exchange-logos/)

It would be nice to update https://stackexchange.com/about/logos to contain SVG versions. (Feel free to use mine, of course!)