# Why does StackExchange not use scaling (vector) graphics?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, design, zoom

I just accidentally scrolled the size in my browser (FF24.2.0) and I noticed that the graphics in the stack exchange network (meta, se, android, code golf as far as I can see at least) don't scale and get blurry instead.

Before:
[image: sharp]

After:
[image: blurry]

I hope you can see the difference, if not try it for yourself (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>scroll</kbd> in most browsers). Even the `upvote` and `downvote` arrows get a bit blurry. I am an **absolute beginner** on the topics of graphics and I would not know the first thing about how to change this stuff, but I wanted to share my confusion.

Is there a particular reason this is not implemented? Is it just not possible? Or has this been answered before and I simply did not find it trough search?

Comment: What you ask for is called [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) and was [already asked before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201772/add-high-resolution-graphics-and-or-svg-icons). :)