# Stackexchange.com uses a raster logo

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, stackexchange.com, logo

Small nitpick, but [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)'s logo is a raster, whereas almost every SE site uses a vector logo (including Meta SE). It's more strange considering [Stack Exchange Inc. provides users with a vector version of their logo](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos), but don't use it themselves.

Not a big deal, but maybe something worth looking into.

Comment: You would almost suspect this rather is a regression of [Add high-resolution-graphics and / or .svg-icons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201772/add-high-resolution-graphics-and-or-svg-icons) that is status-completed ....

Comment: @rene no regression, stackexchange.com was never part of the Q&A sites, so it also never got such love from the design team.